# The YouTube live stream encountered a failure

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We are currently utilizing the ffmpeg library for streaming on YouTube Live. However, we have faced issues in a recent live streaming session that initially functioned correctly but encountered errors around the 13 to 15-minute mark. The error logs from FFmpeg during this session are as follows:

**Live Stream 1 Error:(Attempt 1)**

> ffmpeg [flv @ 0x555c4bdfe680] Failed to update header with correct
> duration. 2023-09-07T23:06:38.490+05:30 [flv @ 0x555c4bdfe680] Failed
> to update header with correct filesize. 2023-09-07T23:06:38.491+05:30
> failed => rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key......
> 2023-09-07T23:06:38.491+05:30
> ffmpeg [tee @ 0x555c48843700] **Slave
> muxer #1 failed: Broken pipe, continuing with 1/2 slaves.**

**Live Stream 2 Error (Attempt 2):**

> **Slave muxer #1 failed: Connection reset by peer, continuing with 1/2
> slaves.**

It is crucial to note that we have conducted numerous live streams on YouTube without encountering this error previously; this is the first instance of such an issue.

We kindly request your assistance in investigating and providing insights into the underlying problem causing these error messages. Any guidance or support you can offer in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, have you resolved the issue or are you still facing it? If it has been solved, could you kindly share some insights?

Comment: hi g8bhawani, the issue remains unresolved, and I am still seeking assistance with this matter.

Comment: This error occurs when the client disconnects due to a lost peer connection. We can solve it temporarily by executing the same command if it's not happening always.